# Sign email depending on domain

Tags: email, postfix-mta, dkim

I've got multiple websites running on the same server, and I'm about to setup DKIM signatures for all of them. I followed [this excellent guide](https://www.megagod.net/2012/05/opendkim-and-postfix-on-debian/) and could successfully send signed emails from PHP on the first try.

The problem is that now all the outgoing emails are signed with the same domain, while I'd like them to be signed by respective domain instead. I can choose which emails to sign via the signing table, but it seems like I can't choose to sign all outgoing emails from domain X with signature Y.

Is this possible, and in that case - how do I do?

Thank you in advance.

---

- **OS:** Debian
- **Web server:** Nginx + PHP-FPM
- **Mail server:** Postfix
- **DKIM:** OpenDKIM

Comment: The guide clearly states `EmailPattern CorrespondingKeyID`, what email pattern are you using to get the emails signed? you can use *@firstdomain.com to limit it to just `firstdomain.com`

Comment: That will only sign emails from a `@firstdomain.com` address - not from any address. What I'm asking for is to sign emails depending on domain, not email address. :-)

Comment: You can use regex here, so `*@firstdomain.com` will sign anything from that domain, so I don't see the problem

Comment: You are talking about the email address while I'm talking about the actual domain. There's the problem. Please read the question again.